# Odd "undefined reference" error

Tags: c, makefile, linker-errors

So I'm trying to make a really simple abstraction library on top of the Windows API using C. I made a simple Makefile and when I try to make the project using Msys, I get this:

```
winapi.o: In function `get_client_pid':
(long path)/winapi.c:13: undefined reference to `GetExtendedTcpTable'
(long path)/winapi.c:31: undefined reference to `GetExtendedTcpTable'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [lib] Error 1
```

and get_client_pid() is defined in winapi.c as

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Iphlpapi.h>

#define true 1
#define false 0


    uint32_t get_client_pid()
    {
        MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID *tcpTable;
        PDWORD tableSize;
        DWORD ret = GetExtendedTcpTable(tcpTable, 
                                        tableSize, 
                                        true, 
                                        2, 
                                        TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL,
                                        0);

        if (ret == NO_ERROR) {
            printf("ERROR get_client_pid: No error with table size at 0?\n");
            return 0;
        }
        if (ret != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
            printf("ERROR get_client_pid: No insufficient buffer with table size at 0?\n");
            return 0;
        }
        printf("TABLE SIZE %d\n", *tableSize);
        tcpTable = malloc(*tableSize);

        ret = GetExtendedTcpTable(  tcpTable,
                                    tableSize, 
                                    true,
                                    2,
                                    TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL,
                                    0);

        if (ret != NO_ERROR) {
            printf("ERROR get_client_pid: GetExtendedTcpTable error: %d\n", ret);
            free(tcpTable);
            return 0;
        }

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < tcpTable->dwNumEntries; i++) {
            MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID row = tcpTable->table[i];
            if (row.dwRemotePort == 0x208 && row.dwRemoteAddr == 0x100007F) {
                printf("FOUND PROCESS: %d\n", row.dwOwningPid);
                free(tcpTable);
                return row.dwOwningPid;
            }
        }

        free(tcpTable);
        return 0;
    }
```

As this is a linker error, I'll add my makefile:

```
current_dir = $(shell pwd)

all: test

test: lib
    gcc -c -g tests.c
    gcc -o tests.exe tests.o -L$(current_dir) -lwinapi

lib:
    gcc -c -g winapi.c
    gcc -shared -o winapi.dll winapi.o -lIphlpapi -luser32

clean:
    rm *.o
```

I have to say that I tried every possible place to insert "-lIphlpapi" in case the linking was somehow in the wrong order but that didn't help.

Comment: C++ name mangling issue?

Comment: Try adding a call to a function from user32 and see if that links

Comment: I'm not entirely happy with your makefile btw. winapi.dll should depend upon winapi.o, which should depend upon winapi.c. `clean` should remove tests.exe and winapi.dll.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst I'm a bit of a beginner so the makefile isn't much. I'll add those changes. I just tested it and IsWindow() from user32 doesn't return a link error.

Comment: Clutching at straws, have you tried changing the case:  "-liphlpapi" rather than "-lIphlpapi"?

Comment: Just tried it out. Same error :/ The linker seems to find the library though. Changing its name to some random string returns with an error that it cant find the library. I don't get that error with "-liphlpapi", lower case i or not

Comment: did you verify that the library has the function with the argument types that you specify? Double check the prototype definition in the include file and match it against the call.

Comment: Neither `GetExtendedTcpTable`, nor `GetAdaptersAddresses` will link, although AFAICT all of the other functions in iphlpapi will. `objdump --syms` says they're both in the library. The only funny thing I can see that they have in common is that they are both in an  `#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501)` block in iphlpapi.h, and none of the other functions are.

Comment: The libs probably came with Mingw as I did not build or download them. I tried printing out the value of _WIN32_WINNT in my case. It's 0x0400 which according to this list (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6sehtctf%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) means I'm running Windows NT 4.0. Im actually on Windows 10.

Comment: That's your problem. If you put `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00`before the `#include Iphlpapi.h` it will build.

Comment: To even get `winapi.c` to compile, I have to add `#include <winsock2.h>` at the top. Just to be clear - you're getting the error when creating the `winapi.dll`, before creating the `tests.exe` program, right?  Also, can you let us know which MinGW toolchain you're using?  The one I tested with (TDM64 4.9.2) does not restrict the `GetExtendedTcpTable()` API to a particular `_WIN32_WINNT` version (rightly or wrongly). And it defaults to `_WIN32_WINNT==0x0502`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MinGW defines `WINVER` as `0x400` (Windows NT) in windef.h, and this means that some newer features of Windows will not link.

```
#ifndef WINVER
#define WINVER 0x0400
/*
 * If you need Win32 API features newer the Win95 and WinNT then you must
 * define WINVER before including windows.h or any other method of including
 * the windef.h header.
 */
#endif
```

So you need to define `WINVER` yourself to the version of Windows you are targeting *before* including any Windows headers.

Use one of the following definitions:

```
#define WINVER 0x0500 // Windows 2000
#define WINVER 0x0501 // Windows XP
#define WINVER 0x0502 // Windows Server 2003
#define WINVER 0x0600 // Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008
#define WINVER 0x0601 // Windows 7
#define WINVER 0x0602 // Windows 8
#define WINVER 0x0603 // Windows 8.1
#define WINVER 0x0A00 // Windows 10
```